# Eliminate VWO Flash of Original Content (FOOC)

Tags: ab-testing, vwo

When using the VWO ab/editor you have the option of editing both the css and js of the page. If you do edit the css/js of the page you will probably see a FOOC when testing out the a/b test. Obviously this is not ideal for the end user. What can you do to avoid FOOC when using VWO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate FOOC in VWO by

1. Click on the element that you are changing, selecting it's immediate parent with the select parent button.[image: vwo editor]
2. From here you will push the HIDE button of the immediate parent.
3. Now you will repeat steps 1 and 2 but push the SHOW button of the immediate parent.

VWO will now add javascript that looks a little like this

```
vwo_$("immediate-parent-of-changed-element").css({"visibility":"visible"});
```

This javascript snippet ensures that the parent of your changed element will not appear until the your changes have been made, eliminating FOOC.